# a plug in i just created in spinning nonstop. any help is appreciated

Tags: wordpress, plugins, spinner

I am building a simple plugin for a wordpress website, that uploads uploads a photo and some CHARS to the database. I am using soho hotel theme. when submit button is clickes, there are no errors but the site keep spinning nonstop.  Any help will be so much appreciated.
this is the form and how it behaves

there are no explicit debuging mesages and errors in the db, so I have not tried much to soleve this misteerious error

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: You'll need to share some code if you want us to help. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more details.